# Is the communication between hibernate and database synchronized?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

If the duration of an operation by hibernate is observed of t second, is this means the database time consumption of handling this operation committed by hibernate must lower than t second?

Thanks for the comments.

For a simple example that how t is observed:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
/* doing a save or select or saveOrUpdate here*/
List<Object[]> resultList = HibernateUtil.select(selectSqlString);
HibernateUtil.saveOrUpdate(collections);
...
/*****************/
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long t = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
```

Comment: Probably yes, but depends on how you measure the "duration of an operation".  Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: Since an "operation by hibernate" does not neccessarily mean that the operation is commited to the database, your assumption does not hold true.